# Dump memory with GDB by register

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, cpu-registers, memory-dump

In $a1 register I have the address that I want to dump and in $a2 register I have the size I want to dump

I have tried to write in GDB

```
x/$a2 $a1
```

But I got

```
 A syntax error in expression,  near $a1
```

What can I do please?

Comment: You can only specify literal numbers as the count parameter of `x`. As a workaround you could use `eval`, like: `eval "x/%d $a1",$a2`